# Реализация LEFT JOIN соединения в ActiveRecord приложения на Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

Как реализовать `LEFT JOIN` соединение в ActiveRecord приложения на Ruby on Rails? Допустим имеется две таблицы `catalogs` и `items` и необходимо вывести список каталогов с количеством позиций в них (даже если в каталоге нет ни одной позиции). На чистом SQL задача бы решалась следующим образом

```
SELECT
  c.id AS id,
  c.name AS name,
  COUNT(i.id) AS total
FROM
  catalogs AS c
LEFT JOIN
  items AS i
ON
  c.id = i.catalog_id
GROUP BY
  c.id

 id |   name    | total
----+-----------+-------
  2 | Каталог 2 |     2
  1 | Каталог 1 |     0
  3 | Каталог 3 |     1
```

Как выполнить такой запрос средствами ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создадим для таблиц `catalogs` и `items` модели связанные 1:N. Причем в модели `Catalog` дополнительно создадим метод `total`, который будет обращаться к вычисляемому столбцу `total` в результирующем запросе (такого столбца в таблице `catalogs` по факту нет).

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :catalog
end

class Catalog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  def total
    self[:total]
  end
end
```

### До версии Rails 5

До версии Rails 5 доступен только метод `joins`, в котором конструкции `LEFT JOIN` и `ON` следует прописать явно. Причем воспользоваться назначением алиасов `AS` не получится - имена таблиц придется прописывать явно. Помимо этого придется явно прописать все столбцы таблицы `catalogs`, дополнив их выражением `COUNT(i.id) AS total`.

```
catalogs = Catalog
             .joins('LEFT JOIN items ON catalogs.id = items.catalog_id')
             .select('catalogs.id AS id, catalogs.name AS name, COUNT(items.id) AS total')
             .group('catalogs.id')

catalogs.collect{|x| [x.id, x.name, x.total] }
=> [[2, "Каталог 2", 2], [1, "Каталог 1", 0], [3, "Каталог 3", 1]]
```

### Rails 5

Начиная с версии Rails 5, в ActiveRecord доступен отдельный метод `left_joins`. В остальном порядок формирования таких запросов и получения результатов, остается таким же.

```
catalogs = Catalog
             .left_joins(:items)
             .select('catalogs.id AS id, catalogs.name AS name, COUNT(items.id) AS total')
             .group('catalogs.id')
catalogs.collect{|x| [x.id, x.name, x.total] }
=> [[2, "Каталог 2", 2], [1, "Каталог 1", 0], [3, "Каталог 3", 1]]
```